# O que fazer quando sua resposta ajuda mais não é dada como melhor

Tags: debate

Acredito que marcar a resposta como **melhor** ajude usuários a conseguirem resolver seus problemas sem precisar varrer as respostas.

Acontece que ultimamente venho percebendo que o usuário que pergunta acaba apenas comentando na resposta *"Obrigado, resolveu"* mas não marca como **melhor**.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- *Eu poderia "cobrar" isso do usuário ?*
- *Como a comunidade vê essa questão de "melhor resposta" ?*

Comment: melhor != aceita. [Devemos pedir para aceitar resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1425/91)

Comment: O verdinho não indica melhor, indica que aquela resposta foi aceita pelo usuário como sendo a que resolveu o problema dele (ou a que ele gostou mais, pra falar a verdade). O "erro" do site é colocar ela no topo, induzindo o leitor a erro, dando exatamente a impressão de que é a melhor. O site seria muito mais claro e funcional se a ordenação padrão fosse por votação. Poderia até ter um pequeno aviso na resposta indicando que tem uma aceita, caso ela não seja a primeira, mas o termômetro da qualidade geralmente é o voto (que falha bastante também, mas ainda é mais justo que o accept).

Comment: Só não entendi o downvote.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre o negativo não foi meu, mas já te adianto que aqui no Meta às vezes o negativo é usado como sinal de "discordo", e não de "errado". Se bem que no caso da sua, acho que não tem muito o que concordar ou discordar, apenas responder esclarecendo.

Comment: Apesar de eu discordar, o próprio sistema diz que a resposta aceita é a melhor. Pairem o cursor sobre um ✅ e vejam o texto: https://i.stack.imgur.com/89qFh.png

Comment: @Math Por isso perguntei, entende ? Se o sistema indica como melhor, fica meio que contraditório, pois nele mesmo diz que a melhor resposta pode não ser a melhor resposta.

Comment: Entendo, mas resolvi destacar pois acredito que muita gente não sabia desse texto, é só para se atentarem.